# Sum data based off a criteria and a odd row number

Tags: excel

Here is an image of the spreadsheet to give a reference to what I'm talking about

[image]

I need to sum the Grey cells in column C when it says "Machine Cycle" next to them in column B.

All of the Grey cells are in odd row numbers.

I would like to try and do this with a formula if possible.  If not I'll just code it in VBA based on color or location relevant to "Machine Cycle"

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just offset the ranges in a SUMIF():

```
=SUMIF($B$2:$B$1040000,"Machine Cycle",C3:C1040001)
```

As you can see the range in column b starts on row two,the value is kept in the first cell of a merged cell.

Then since we want the value one row down from that in Column C we set the range as the same size but one row down.

[image]

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  I didn't know that merged cells held that value of the first Cell.  This works great as far as I can tell.  I'll make sure and than check mark it.  Thanks.